# moment js two datetimepicker time comperison

Tags: javascript, momentjs, datetimepicker

I have 2 daettimepickers start_date_time and end_date_time
want
on $(end,start).change, I want to compare if more than 6 hours difference show alert and clear input

```
$('.dateTo,.dateFrom').blur(function () {
            if ($('.dateFrom').val() !== '' && $('.dateTo').val() !== '') {

                var fromTime = moment($('.dateFrom').val(),"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                var toTime = moment($('.dateTo').val(), "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                console.log(fromTime + ' - ' + toTime); 
                //above returns 1135054800000 - 1166562000000
                //while i expect formated as above
                var duration = moment.duration(toTime.diff(fromTime));
                var hours = duration.asHours();
                console.log(hours);
                //return 8752 in meridiam is changed (from 04/12/2019 9:am to 05/12/2019 1pm)
                if (fromTime >= toTime) {
                    $(this).val('');
                    alert('ToTime should be greater than fromTime.');
                }
                var diffMs = (toTime - fromTime)
                var diffMins = Math.floor(diffMs / 60000);

                if (diffMins > (6 * 60) && $(".PermissionType").val()=="Personal") {
                    $(this).val('');
                    alert('Duration should not increase 6 hours.');
                }
            }
        });
```

`var duration = moment.duration(toTime.diff(fromTime));
 var hours = duration.asHours();`

above lines return wrong difference of hours when AM/PM is different in start and end datetime

I need difference of hours in `05/12/2019 11:00 PM` and `06/12/2019 12:00 AM` it is returning me `8761`
while  `05/12/2019 11:00 PM` and `05/12/2019 11:59 PM` returns `0.9833333333333333`

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this and I can't reproduce your issue. Using `datetime-local` inputs lets you select the time and it's getting the proper am/pm formatting.

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="start">
<input type="datetime-local" id="end">
```

here's a fiddle demonstrating https://jsfiddle.net/fLzu854x/

Looking at the console in my fiddle, I am not getting that error.

[image: Screenshot of console with 11:00PM to 11:59PM giving 0.983[1]]

[image: Screenshot of console with 11:00PM to 12:00AM the following day giving 1[2]]

Comment: You need to clarify what you're asking. What is the difference you're getting? what should it be?

Comment: I need difference of hours in `05/12/2019 11:00 PM` and `06/12/2019 12:00 AM` it is returning me `8761`

Comment: @alamnaryab Can you provide an example where you're getting that error?

Comment: brother first thing I will need datetimepicker control, in chrome it is not showing me anything to select time

Comment: [datetime pickers are obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime) use datetime-local.